# How to commit a file, if it was modified after the file was added and committed

Tags: git

I have a problem that I `git add today.c` then I `git commit today.c`, by this step, the file `today.c` has been modified (I use a shell script to do this modify), then I push the file to `origin master`, but the file is still the same, it is not modified, but in my working directory, `today.c` is truly been modified.

How can I push the modified file to the `origin master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you commit a change in a file and then push the changes to another branch, only the commits are pushed into this branch, in your case, to `origin`.

You changed your file after the commit, so it is modified in your working copy, but it is not yet registered as a commit in your repository. That's why a `push` won't change the file in your remote repository.
To do this, you have to commit the file again and then push the new commit.

See this explained instruction set:

```
git add today.c
git commit -m "First change" # Creates commit 1
./your_magical_shell_script_changes_today.c
git push origin master # Only commit 1 exists, therefore, only this is pushed to master
git add today.c
git commit -m "Changed by the shell script" # Here, the commit 2 is created
git push origin master # Now it is pushed to origin, too.
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i don't mean to do "git add, commit,push" again, if in this case, i have no need to change the file in 'git commit' step, i can just modify the file first, and then 'add, commit, push' it. But now what i want is how to renew the file and push it. I have tried to use a lot of ways, but all failed, I think i should modify the file in the 'git add' step, but how?

Comment: Sorry that you don't want to do "git add, commit, push", but you have to do this. This is how Git works. If you want to skip the add step, you can use `git commit -am "Second commit"` to commit directly. The push is required, though

Answer (score -1):

Siguang, could you please do the following?
`git add today.c`
`git commit -m 'modify'`
`git push origin master`
And check again.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i don't want to do git add, git commit, git push again, this would be to complicated.

Comment: Why have you clicked '-1'?

Comment: I didn't click '-1', btw, I can't change it, when i change it, it will become '-1'again, i don't know why.

Comment: @guerda has clicked '-1'. You can't rate answers until you have 15 reputation as I remember.